# How to debug a whole web page with firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

suppose i am seeing the site http://www.webspiders.com/ and i want set break point and debug the whole page. whenever i click or mouse over any element and for this action if any javascript is fired then i need to see and debug that javascript too. please help me with detail instruction for debugging with firebug. thanks.

Comment: Are you trying step thru all mouse events on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know where to place your breakpoints or must place a breakpoint ta all reachable members of every js file. A help would be the framework that the site use, if the is any.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable the "Break On Next" button near the top left of the "Script" tab of Firebug.  Once enabled, Firebug will break as soon as JavaScript is executed.

Comment: sorry the tips does not work. so please see ur self. just go to http://www.webspiders.com/ this site and do the same u said to me and just hover your mouse on left side panel bar. when u place ur mouse once left side panel bar then a some ting will come out. there a javascript is firing but ur tips will show the javascript function name or body.

Comment: Hi Thomas, what happens for you when you enable "Break On Next"?  For me, it breaks on the next JavaScript execution...even on webspiders.com.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html)'s a tutorial on setting breakpoints in Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

On the firebug script tab: 
 1. click on the number where you want to break the script
 2. refresh